# Apache - Domain not resolving : 404 errors

Tags: apache, whm

My Centos 5.1 VPS (WHM) had to be hard rebooted earlier and all the sites apart from one have come back online.  The non working domain pings with 0% packet loss so it looks as though Apache is serving, however, I get the error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I checked the DNS settings and as expected, they point to the host. I checked the permissions and CHMOD values for the public_html folder and they are all correct.  I restarted Apache and BIND but I still can't get the domain to work.  Incidentally, adding erroneous characters to .htaccess (in an attempt to produce an error), does not make any difference.  The host did a system file check which showed no errors.

What have I missed?

Comment: Have you verified whether Apache tries to load the correct virtual host?

Comment: I ran httpd -S and no warnings or errors were shown.  http.conf appears to reference the virtual host correctly.

Comment: And requests to the site get logged to the site log files? (Assuming you have configured per-site logging.)

Comment: Yes, requests are being logged in the site log files.  I found some errors in the Apache Error log like: "mod_ruid2 www.xxxxx.co.uk GET /images/imagename.gif HTTP/1.1 chdir to /home/virtfs/xxxx failed"